# How to download and enable module needing to subscribe to rss?

Tags: 7, feeds, files

I want to download and install "Node Redirect" module for version 7 of Drupal but I can't find a way to subscribe to rss as needed. What are the steps to follow to download the module?

Answer (score 0):

In the right side menu there will a link [Browse code repository](http://drupalcode.org/project/node_redirect.git). There you can find git clone URL

```
git://git.drupal.org/project/node_redirect.git
```

So you can clone it.

Comment: Can you please explain to me the procedure a bit further. I have never done anything similar.

Comment: I still wonder, it is a drupal 5.x version. Or can you give me what is your requirement, so that I will provide a better option.

Comment: I have previously created with the display suite a view mode to display some info in a customized way. This view is set in a URL and now I want to change the default /node/% to redirect to /node/%/receipt which is the URL of the new view mode. For this reason (if correctly)  I figured out I have to use 'node redirect' module. But for version 7 drupal I can't find it.

Comment: Then for that sake you can have a look on this module https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect and https://www.drupal.org/project/match_redirect

Comment: I 've tried both the modules you recommended me but I have some issues  with the % symbol I think. Do you have any ideas on that? Thanks a lot for your help